# How to convert Y-m-d H:i:s to Y-m-d in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time

How to convert Y-m-d H:i:s to Y-m-d in PHP?

I have e.g.

```
$date = "2011-08-10 20:40:12";
```

and would like to convert it to just

```
$output = "2011-08-10";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

quick/dirty:

```
$output = substr('2011-08-10 20:40:12', 0, 10);
```

slightly more robust:

```
$output = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2011-08-10 20:40:12'));
```

fairly reliable:

```
$output = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', '2011-08-10-20:40:12')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: In third case on PHP 5.5.4: Fatal error: Class 'Date' not found, but DateTime::createFromFormat() works.

Answer (score 7):

Easily done with [`strtotime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php), and capable of changing to any other date format you may need as well.

```
$old_date = "2011-08-10 20:40:12";
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old_date));
echo $new_date;

// Prints 2011-08-10
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, a simple way to do it would be the following (if you've already gotten the date in a string):

```
$output = substr($date, 0, 10);
```

This would mean that you grab the first 10 characters in "2011-08-10 20:40:12", leaving you with "2011-08-10"!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in php date format function:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

to do this:

```
$date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, thought not as good is to simply do a substring:

```
$newDate = substr($date, 0, 10)
```

Comment: Damn you guys are quick! This one's already been posted

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one thinking this "simple"! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Just use the date format for date only and convert your string to a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `strftime` to date since it's format input matches those in C and other languages.

```
$output = strftime( '%Y-%m-%d', strtotime( $date) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$old_date = "2011-08-10 20:40:12";
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old_date));
echo $new_date;

// Prints 2011-08-10
```

This should be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

A tweak to the method using explode so you can turn it into a one liner:

list($date) = explode(' ', $date);

the list function is very handy for dates.

Another example using list:

list($year, $month, $day) = explode(' ', $date);

Also, you are best to use ' instead of " in strings, unless your string includes variables.

e.g.

- 'yada'
- 'bing'
- "Hello {$bob}"

I'm fed up seeing even the PHP docs use "string" in examples where they should use 'string' :o)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$date = explode(" ",$date);
$output = $date[0];
```

If they are separated by space, you can use explode to separate them.

Comment: Its Gives error can't convert string offset in array.